# If skydivers cannot jump on a flight, what should I take care of when landing?

Tags: landing, skydiving

Piloting an aircraft, if skydivers cannot jump on a flight, what should I take care of when landing?

Are there any special recommendations which should be taken into account?

Answer (score 20):

You should descend in a controlled way, taking into account that your descent rate should be ≤ 29 mph (less than 13 m/s), once below 2,500 feet.

If the descent rate is higher than that, then there is a risk of the [AAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_activation_device) popping the skydiver's reserve parachute, mid-flight.

Comment: If I've done the conversion properly, 13m/s = 2559.1ft/min.

Comment: Pilots do not typically have a vertical speed indicator other than feet per minute...

Comment: There was actually an incident in Germany in 2009, where the parachute opened and the guy (who never intended to jump, and was only along for the ride) was actually pulled from the plane. The BFU [published the report](http://www.bfu-web.de/EN/Publications/Investigation%20Report/2009/Report_09_CX008_Cessna206_Stadtlohn_ParachuteDeployment.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) last month. Very scary stuff, have a look at the picture of how he had ripped through the fuselage on his way out (page 7).

Comment: That is to say, he didn't actually go through the fuselage, he did, however put a considerable dent in the door frame. Luckily, under the circumstances, it held together and the pilot was able to land.

Comment: @inafziger in the US maybe ;)

Comment: @DanPichelman http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13+m%2Fs+in+feet%2Fmin agrees at least within 0.1ft/min

Comment: can't the guy reset the AAD to prevent activation?

Comment: That would require for some rigs to be taken off, which is less than feasable when in a confined space. Also by the time everyone on a flight has switched off his AAD, the plane would  practically already be down.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps trivial, but your landing weight will be higher than during a standard run sans skydivers, which will have an impact on stall speed, landing distance etc.